# Passing NetworkCredential through WCF service to use with EWS API

Tags: c#, wcf, exchangewebservices

I have a WCF service running, hosted on IIS7 which is exposed using a netTcp endpoint, and configured using Windows authentication (`Transport` security and `clientCredentialType="Windows"`), and this all works fine.

In the service I am using the EWS API to send email, and check inboxes on the Exchange server. I have this working in part, in so far as at the moment in development I have manually specified the Credentials property by creating a `NetworkCredential` object to pass in.

What I want to do though is use the identity of the user calling the service so I can send mail as them and iterate through their inbox.

I can get access to the calling user details by using

```
ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity
```

but this returns an `IIdentity` object and not the credentials I need to create a connection to the Exchange server.

I cannot obviously create a `NetworkCredential` object without the password, which I don't have, and from what I can see I cannot create a `NetworkCredential` from the `IIdentity` object.

There must be a way to achieve this. All suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
using(ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate())
{
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(...)
    service.UseDefaultCredentials = true; 

}
```

The client, that calls your server must allow delegation:

```
proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Delegation;
```

If your WCF server runs using localSystem or NetworkService account, you also need to enable "Trusted for delegation" property for your computer account in AD (typically a job of a network administrator). If it runs using another domain user account, you need to enable "Trusted for delegation" property for that account and create Server Principal Name (SPN) for your server. Honestly, I never did that myself because I prefer to use the NetworkService account. Her come a couple of links: [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907272) , [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647248.aspx), [and here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730088.aspx)

Comment: Great idea and I was hopeful, but that throws an exception: `The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeServiceBase' threw an exception.`

Comment: What kind of exception? Maybe you need to configure delegation to make it work?

Comment: If your remote client connects to your server, and your server calls the Exchange server (on a remote computer), delegation needs to be configured for your server.

Comment: It's a TypeInitializationException exception: `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070542)`

Comment: Looking at the `WindowsIdentity` object the `ImpersonationLevel` is set to  Identification. Should that be something else?

Comment: Yep, client is on one machine, IIS host on another, and the Exchange on a third. All are on the same network and domain. Do you have any pointers or links to delegation?

Comment: Allow delegation in the client proxy first, I'll try to find something useful.

Comment: Which client needs delegation, the IIS server that is calling the Exchange box? Or the actual client application?

Comment: The client, an actual user, that has a mailbox.

Comment: Thanks for all the info. We are running the service AppPool as a specific domain user account, to allow for permissions etc on other resources. I'll look through the info you've added and let you know how I get on.